# Multicast doesn't seem to be working on RHEL 5.5

Tags: networking, redhat, multicast

I'm trying to install Oracle Grid Infrastructure on two machines. [Their documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e17212/prelinux.htm#CEGGIDCG) states:

> You must enable multicasting for the cluster on the IP address subnet ranges 224.0.0.0/24 and 230.0.1.0/24

So I ran:

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0/24 dev eth2
route add -net 230.0.1.0/24 dev eth2
```

`route -n` produces:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
230.0.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
224.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
# and others
```

An `ifconfig eth2` shows, among other things, `UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST`.

However, when I run their multicast test utility, it fails me:

```
Test for Multicast address 230.0.1.0
Sep  3 19:40:39 | Multicast Failed for eth2 using address 230.0.1.0:42000

Test for Multicast address 224.0.0.251
Sep  3 19:41:10 | Multicast Failed for eth2 using address 224.0.0.251:42001
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you open the necessary ranges in your firewall?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think I have a firewall enabled. How would I know if I did? `iptables --list` doesn't give me anything.

Comment: Is multicast enabled on the switch/router where your machines are connected to?

Answer (score 2):

What's the output of `netstat -gn`?

By default, your multicast joins are going to go out of the lowest-numbered interface *cough, eth0*. Since you're attempting to do this via eth2, you're going to need another step to establish connectivity.

Does the test utility provide a means of specifying the interface? If so, you'll need to explicitly state "eth2". If that is not an option, you can add another static route to make sure your multicast traffic uses that interface.

Something like:

`route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth2` (route all multicast through eth2)

Try that...

If it all works, be sure to make everything persistent by creating a `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth2` file with your static routes.

Edit:

If you have the ability to select interfaces in your application, then you *DO NOT* need any static routes on your interfaces. It would be up to the Oracle test utility to handle IGMP.

Try that first...

If that does not work, please verify if multicast is enabled on the network switch that the systems are connected to. What type of switches are they? I can give more detail instructions based on the switch model/type. If Cisco, for instance...

```
sh ip igmp snooping
sh run | i multicast-routing
```

Following that, there seems to be a [known bug related to this product](http://www.oracleangels.com/2011/05/grid-infrastrcture-multicast-issue.html). Are you certain that you're fully-patched? It appears to be an unpublished patch, so you may have to go to Oracle to resolve this if everything else is in place.

See: [Grid infrastructure multicast issue - Oracle Bug 9974223](http://www.oracleangels.com/2011/05/grid-infrastrcture-multicast-issue.html)

Comment: Here's the output of `netstat -gn`: http://pastebin.com/r5hLn76p ; and yes, the utility allows me to specify the interface (I'm using eth2)

Comment: @nulluser  Yeah, joins going out of eth0, probably. You didn't answer my question about whether the test utility allows you to specify an interface. That makes a difference!

Comment: It does. I'm specifying eth2.

Comment: Hmm... Remove the route statements you have, then re-add them. Maybe add the one I specified first. Try that. If it doesn't work, then we'd need to look at `tcpdump`. You *are* making the changes on both  servers, right?

Comment: 224.0.0.0/24 is subnet local and all multicast-capable interfaces will be (and must be) able to join.  The other potential issue is rpf - if the source of the 230.x.x.x group is not local then there could potentially be problems if the unicast routes don't correspond.

Comment: @ewwhite I tried adding that route first, to no avail. Yes, I am making changes on both servers. When I run tcpdump on eth2 it fails to capture anything at all, on either server.

Comment: @NullUser See my edits above. Remove the static routes.

Comment: @NullUser Did this work for you?

Comment: @ewwhite Not really. Strangely enough it was working for `eth0` but not `eth2`. I ended up copying `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to `eth2` (modifying the relevant parameters) and it worked. Unfortunately I lost the original `ifcfg-eth2` file so I don't know what I've effectively changed.

Comment: @NullUser What about the known Oracle bug linked in my answer?

Comment: I read it before asking the question; it doesn't really apply.