# diagnostic multicast issue using wireshark

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, multicast

I have a network that is setup for multicast traffic. My setup is the following

```
-Machine A : a server generates multicast traffic.
-Machine A : few clients subscribing to that multicast traffic
-Machine B : few clients subscribing to that multicast traffic

# Address I am using
IP  : 239.193.0.21
PORT: 20401
```

The clients in machine A , even if they join the group (I can see IGMP messages through wireshark), don't receive any data while (and this is the funny part) machine B,C and D receive everything.

I sorted that issue by completely disabling Linux firewall.

Before doing that, I enabled the multicast on the firwall ('reject all').

```
 iptables -A INPUT -m addrtype --src-type MULTICAST -j ACCEPT
```

My question is the following: what I can check in wireshark that can help me in spot such firewall issues in the futures? For `TCP/IP` I realize by using `ping` and looking at `ICMP` packets rejected.

What I can check/monitor for multicast?

I am using LInux/Red-Hat Enterprise 6.2

Comment: How many interfaces are on the client systems?

Comment: Hi. I have 2 network interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the troubleshooting steps I noted at: [Multicast doesn't seem to be working on RHEL 5.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/424031/multicast-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-on-rhel-5-5/424035#424035)

But in short, with multiple interfaces, are you sure your joins are going out of the right interface? What are the IP addresses involved? Do you have control of the client application and does it have a way of selecting which interface it uses?

Comment: HI. At the end there was some strange setting in the router. Only our network engineer figure it out. We now use multicast netcat to quick testing multicast.